# Passing strongly typed object to method expecting an interface

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm running into difficulty passing a strongly typed object, `AttractView`, to another method, `addView()` which expects an `IWizardView` interface that `AttractView` does implement.

When I pass it as-is (as shown below), I get the compile error `CaptureApplication.as, Line 120 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type AttractView to an unrelated type IWizardView.`

Casting to either `IWizardView` or `BaseView` before passing yields a similar error at run time.

Application class:

```
public class CaptureApplication extends MovieClip
{
    public var attractView : AttractView;
    public var captureView : CaptureView;
    public var reviewView : ReviewView;
    public var completeView : CompleteView;
    protected var wizard : Wizard;

    public function CaptureApplication()
    {
        // Create views
        attractView = new AttractView();
        captureView = new CaptureView();
        reviewView = new ReviewView();
        completeView = new CompleteView();

        // Create wizard and add views to sequence
        wizard = new Wizard( this );
        wizard.addView( attractView );
        wizard.addView( captureView );
        wizard.addView( reviewView );
        wizard.addView( completeView );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Wizard:

```
public class Wizard extends EventDispatcher
{
    // ...

    public function addView ( pView : IWizardView ) : void
    {
        // ...
    }

    //...
}
```

And an example view:

```
public class AttractView extends BaseView implements IWizardView
{
    // ...
}
```

Architecture I'm hoping for (simplified for clarity):

```
CAPTURE LIBRARY (AS3 SWC)
/ classes
    / wizard
        / IWizardView
        / Wizard
    / capture
        / IView
        / BaseView
        / AttractView
        / CaptureView
        / (etc.)

CAPTURE APPLICATION (Flash)
/ classes
    / CaptureApplication
```

The idea here is that I am building multiple "capture" applications with similar UIs, so I'd like to extract common elements into a library and extend as necessary for each unique capture app.

**Update 1:**

`IWizardView` and `Wizard` actually live in a separate library SWC that is included in the `CaptureApplication` project. It's also worth noting that both the FLA *and* the FB project are including the SWC. Perhaps there's a conflict? As soon as I moved all classes from the library to the project and removed the SWC from the project and FLA, it worked.

I will have some more time to play and investigate tomorrow. Update to follow.

**Update 2:**

I've found where my architecture is breaking. I can keep my interfaces and `BaseView` class in my library SWC just fine. The problem occurs as soon as I try to move my views (`AttractView`, etc.) from my application project into the library SWC. My libs folder is merged into code, not real-time shared. Any ideas?

Comment: yep. Should definitely work. ... hmmm

Comment: Have you modules and loaded SWFs with code?

Comment: Does each view throw the same error (capture, review and complete)?

Comment: @Constantiner- Nope, no modules or loaded SWFs. The `IWizardView`, `Wizard` and `BaseView` are in a SWC library, though. I'll try moving those to the same project just for the heck of it.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using a Flash Builder CS4.5 project, with CaptureApplication.fla being a Flash CS5.5 FLA. Both the FLA and FB project reference the SWC library.

Comment: @Bosworth99- Yup, they all give the same error when commenting the others out. The classes are actually empty right now.

Comment: Lo and behold, as soon as I take the external SWC library out of the picture, it works! Now I need to figure out what exactly was going on, because I would think that should still work. Either way, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @Constantiner.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know this may not work is when you are loading some parts of your application into different application domains or if the application domains you are using reside in different security domains (in wich case application domains will be different regardless of whatever you do).

This can happen when aplpication domain containing `IWizardView` in `Wizard` differs from the application domain where `AttractView` resides. This happens only when loading application parts (and may be when embedding with [Embed] also -- not really sure.)

If this is the case, you may even have completely same qualified class and interface names, but still get coercion errors. Note: in Flash Builder you can see memory adresses of declarations which you can compare (particularly in exception messages).

Refer to these parts of documentation:

- [LoaderContext.applicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#applicationDomain)
- [LoaderContext.securityDomain](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#securityDomain)
- [ApplicationDomain class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)
- [Using the ApplicationDomain class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e07.html)

If this is not the case and you are not loading anything anywhere, please elaborate your question a bit. I'm really curious what is the issue about.

**EDIT** Articles on application domains for code in SWC used as RSL.

- [Specifying domains for RSLs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-64f4fc4712daa436650-7fff)
- [Same Domain: Runtime Shared Libraries](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/?page=2#SameDomainRuntimeSharedLibraries)

Comment: I think that's is the gist of it. I mentioned in the question comments that `IWizardView` and `Wizard` actually live in a shared library SWC that I was loading into my FB project containing the specific views (`AttractView`, `CaptureView`, etc.). As soon as I moved the classes from the library project to the app project, it worked. It seems a little weird to me that I can't do this at compile-time. Run-time, I understand. I'm going to do a little playing tomorrow to pinpoint exactly what makes it fail and, hopefully, how to get around it while keeping my library external.

Comment: If you use SWC as a real-time shared library (not merged into code), you may need to see these articles: [Specifying domains for RSLs on help.adobe.com](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-64f4fc4712daa436650-7fff), [Same Domain: Runtime Shared Libraries on senocular.com](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/?page=2#SameDomainRuntimeSharedLibraries)

Comment: I've found where my architecture is breaking. I can keep my interfaces and `BaseView` class in my library SWC just fine. The problem occurs as soon as I try to move my views (`AttractView`, etc.) from my application project into the library SWC. My libs folder is merged into code, not real-time shared. Any ideas?

Comment: The details are still a bit obscure to me. In cases like that I create a standalone test stripped of everything but the behaviour in question. Can you replicate it in a dummy example? If yes -- that's good! -- you know that does not depend on your project specific (and you can share that dummy project to discuss the problem). If not -- that's a bit worse -- you must refine your scope of analysis and make dummy malfunction just the same way the original project does.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `AttractView` as an `IWizardView` in your public member:

```
public var attractView : IWizardView;
```

I think if you want it to be recognized as an interface it has to be typed as one. Which shouldn't be a problem for you if your design is implemented properly since that's kinda the point of an interface.

*the more I think about it, the more I think I ran into this issue before*

Comment: I tried various incarnations of this. The problem is that I then can't create instances of my views in my `CaptureApplication` class as shown in my example. I'm using an interface so that my `Wizard` class can interact with the views through methods like `next()`, `previous()`, etc.

Comment: Of course, changing this will change something major in the way your application works, but it is probably for the better.

Comment: I also tried casting in my assignment: `attractView = IWizardView( new AttractView() )`. Yields the same convert error at runtime. Using `as` just makes `pView` null. It traces out as expected in `CaptureApplication`.